# Spring jdbcTemplate: generic code to run a select query with model name provided

Tags: java, spring, generics, spring-jdbc

Below is the working code that assumes MyModel class is the model class.

```
void runSql(String sql) {

    List<MyModel> models = JdbcTemplate.query(sql, params, new BeanPropertyRowMapper(MyModel.class));

    for (MyModel model : models) {

    ...
    }
}
```

How to write generic version of above method that will take model name such as "MyModel" as a String.

The best I could thought of is the below code. However, it is throwing ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to MyModel.

```
void runSql(String sql, String modelName) {

    Class modelClass = modelName.getClass();

// how to replace List<MyModel> with something like List<modelClass.getName()>
    List<MyModel> models = JdbcTemplate.query(sql, params, new BeanPropertyRowMapper(modelClass));

    for (MyModel model : models) { // exception here: ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to MyModel

    ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it depends on how you are going to work with result objects. You can go with somthing like this:

```
void runSql(String sql, String modelName) {

    Class modelClass = Class.forName("com.mycompany.model." + modelName);

    List<?> models = JdbcTemplate.queryForList(sql, modelClass, params);

    for (Object model : models) { 
        //Then you should cast your model manually if you need to
        if (model instanceof MyModel) {
            MyModel myModel = (MyModel) model;
            //do whatever with object of MyModel class
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have to swap modelClass and params in queryForList() method to remove  compilation error. After running the code, I got run time exception on queryForList: org.springframework.jdbc.IncorrectResultSetColumnCountException: Incorrect column count: expected 1, actual 13 . There are 13 columns in select sql query. FWIW, I am using NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.

Comment: above code compiles, on using JdbcTemplate instead of NamedParameterJdbcTemplate. but, it throws Invalid Column Type exception. However, this exception goes after removing params from queryForList method and hard-coded the values in the query. But, still I am getting  Incorrect column count: expected 1, actual 13 .